# How can I connect and plot parts of 2D slices over a certain threshold?

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface, mplot3d

I want to connect binary surfaces in a surfaceplot, to achive a 3D connecting contour.

So far I plotted the 2D slices in this minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d   import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,20), np.linspace(0,1,20))
z = np.linspace(0, 2, 4)

u = np.zeros((len(z),20,20))

for i in range(len(z)):
    u[i, i+5:i+7, i+5:i+7] = 1

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
for i in range(len(z)):
    im = ax.pcolor(x, y, u[i,:,:], alpha=0.1) 
    ax.add_collection3d(im, zs=z[i], zdir='z')    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Does anybody have an idea on how to connect these yellow areas to a 3D contour and plot it?
Thanks a lot!
Here is an example of what I want to get:
[image]

Comment: I personally do not understand how you want to connect them. Like, what do you mean? Can you provide with an example figure or with a code you tried?

Comment: There is no general way to connect such 2D slices.  How would an algorithm know which edge in one layer should be connected with which in the other layer? With some additional constraints, e.g. that the contours don't change too much between layers and/or that the contours would form something like a height map, there are approaches that might give a "good enough" result.

Comment: Is there maybe a further possibility to interpolate fields, and to plot structures over a certain threshold? (So, I have a mesh of data which should converted in a 3d grid)